# Same time value in two different cells, different decimal value, no match possible

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I'm trying a index match function on two different cells in which is the time value 08:30:00. I never got a match and after long searching I found that there's a minuscule difference in value between the two cells. By the way they are in two different columns but seem to have the same formatting. Is there any logical explanation for this and is there a way to avoid this?

```
08:30:00
one cell decimal value     0,35416666666666700
other cell decimal value   0,35416666666666600
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ROUND` function to have the times match to your preferred increment.  So, if you want to match your times to the nearest 1/1000th of a second, Round your time values to the 8th digit.  For example `=ROUND(A1,8)`. You should be able to use the Round formula on both sides of your comparison to get a match.

In your sample `=ROUND(0,35416666666666700,8)=ROUND(0,35416666666666600,8)` should return True.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps convert the time into text using the `TEXT` function and formatting the result back to time:

```
=TIME(A1, "hh:mm:ss")*1
```

That should remove all the small differences out.

Apply that to the columns where you're having the lookup and the match values.

Answer (score 0):

Excel cannot use values of time past milliseconds (0.001 seconds). That works out to be the 13th decimal place being the point after which more places are not of value to rounding.

So you can always round to exactly 13 decimal places and not lose any useable accuracy.

(Of course, if one have it as a time AND date where it's stored (not in this case) then those digits are going to cut down the depth to which Excel can distinguish the seconds or tenths, hundredths, and thousandths of seconds, so you would lose three places of significance and I haven't figured just where that puts you vis-a-vis the subdivisions of seconds.)